# Given $G_n$, a graph with $2^n$ vertices, show $G_4\simeq Q_4$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G_n$ denote the $2^n$ vertices graph in which every vertex is labeled with a string of $n$ bits. A pair of vertices are adjacent if and only if their bit strings differ in exactly 3 digits.

> i)Show $G_4\simeq Q_4$ where $Q_n$ denotes the [hypercube graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypercubeGraph.html).
>
> ii) Decide if true or false. Prove or give a counterexample: $G_n$ is bipartite for all $n\geq 4$.

**Attempt:**

For $i)$ what I did was to draw both graphs and tried to find an isomorphism, although I obviously couldn't get it right (pretty hard with 16 vertices), is there a simpler way?

For $ii)$ I drew $G_4$ and saw it was bipartite, so then I tried to use induction on the number of vertices, but I couldn't get it right either.

Answer (score 1):

For $ii)$, it is true.
Let $A_n\subset G_n$ be the set of strings with an even number of $0$'s and let $B_n\subset G_n$ be the set of strings with an odd number of $0$'s.
Clearly $G_n=A_n\cup B_n$.
Observe that, given a string $s\in G_n$, every time you change a digit, the parity of the number of $0$'s changes, so after changing exactly $3$ digits the parity will change.
This implies that no two strings in $A_n$ are adjacent and no two strings in $B_n$ are adjacent.
Therefore $G_n$ is bipartite.

For $i)$ I am afraid that finding the isomorphism explicitly is the only way...